# Parsing XML on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I am using a tutorial for an XML app I am writing but I can not figure out how to change the NSURL to where the XML file is on the iPhone.

```
//XMLAppDelegate.m 

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/...";
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //Initialize the delegate. 
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    //Set delegate [xmlParser setDelegate:parser]; 
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse]; 
    if(success) 
        NSLog(@"No Errors"); 
    else 
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!"); 
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]]; 
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
}
```

Comment: May be ```NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml"];```?

Comment: Please post the code that you're using to load the data file.

Comment: I don't want it reading from a web service.  I need to XML file on the iPhone.  The app must read it from there

Comment: //XMLAppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
 
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 
//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
 
//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
 

BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
 
if(success)
NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
 
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

Comment: Sorry can't seem to format the above code to look nice.  The code is available on the tutorial link above

Comment: In the future, you can edit your question to include the code there. Big chunks of code in comments are pretty much unreadable. If what I've added doesn't match what you're using, please make corrections.

Answer (score 1):

NSURL provides methods for easily creating file URL's, but if the file is one of your application's resources the easiest way to get the URL you need is to use NSBundle:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDataFile" withExtension:@"xml"];
```

Otherwise, you might want to look into `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Comment: OK, so I changed the Url code to the one below however it crashes

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDataFile" withExtension:@"xml"];

Do I need to show the file location for it?

Comment: What's causing the crash? Also, where is your XML file stored? Is it in your app's bundle, in the Documents folder, or somewhere else?

Comment: I believe it is the NSURL function that is causing the crash.  The xml file was put into the resouse folder.  I am not sure if i need to put in a direct path to it or put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the NSURL function that is causing the crash. The xml file was put into the resouse folder. I am not sure if i need to put in a direct path to it or put it somewhere else